# What is Background Processing in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I can implement Background Processing in asp.net. Can anyone give a small and easy sample or provide me a useful link.

thanks.

Comment: Your question title is completely different from your question content. Are you asking what it is, *or* how to do it? Have you searched for any links before asking?

Comment: sorry for that but I want to know it with sample

Comment: Still, your question is not clear. What do you want to get done? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background processing means handling some necessary operations on the background without disrupting asp.net website workings. In synchronous model of operation to receive response from the server, user has to wait for all operations to complete. If there are some operations that do not need users intervention (for example, upon posting to blog send e-mail to all subscribers) they can be processed in background, while user can further interact with a website.

In terms of threads it means that main thread (which processes user request) calls/creates another thread to do part of work in it's stead.

There are 2 ways to use background processing: for operations that are handled periodically - needing application-wide background processing; per user request - needing request-level background processing.

[Here's](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article613-background-processes-in-asp-net-web-applications.aspx) a simple example of backgroundWorker to use for application-wide processing.

To do a request-level background processing you'd need to implement some queue for pending requests and iterate over them using the backgroundWorker presented earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use asynchronous process with ASP.Net Ajax in order to do Background Process. One of advantages using ajax is partial rendering of web page. So you do not have to reload a one whole page.

Here are two example link: [Introduction To Asp .Net Ajax (ScriptManager, UpdatePanel, ContentTemplate, Triggers)](http://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/introduction-to-asp-net-ajax-scriptmanager-updatepanel-contenttemplate-triggers/) and [Introduction to Asp .Net Ajax – 2 (UpdateProgress)](http://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/introduction-to-asp-net-ajax-2-updateprogress/)

Regards,